# Compiling and Running ARM Assembly thumb-2 in Rasperry pi?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi

I am taking an assembly class and turns out i can't run the Assembly program they gave, due to being Windows 95 compliant x.x

I am running Rasperry PI and can easily run the Assembly for ARM code via

http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/

```
/* -- first.s */
/* This is a comment */
.global main /* 'main' is our entry point and must be global */
.func main   /* 'main' is a function */

main:          /* This is main */
    mov r0, #2 /* Put a 2 inside the register r0 */
    bx lr      /* Return from main */

$ as -o first.o first.s
$ gcc -o first first.o
$ ./first ; echo $?
2
```

But this is the standard ARM 32 bit setup and need to compile and run for a thumb-2 setup for example:

```
    AREA PrintText, CODE, READONLY
SWI_WriteC  EQU &0     ;output character in r0 
SWI_Exit    EQU &11    ;finish program
        ENTRY

        BL  Print   ;call print subroutine
        =   "Text to print",&0a,&0d,0   
        ALIGN
        SWI     SWI_Exit    ;finish
Print       LDRB    r0,[r14], #1    ;get a character
        CMP     r0, #0      ;end mark NUL?
        SWINE   SWI_WriteC  ;if not, print
        BNE Print
        ADD r14, r14, #3    ; pass next word boundary
        BIC r14, r14, #3    ; round back to boundary
        MOV pc, r14     ;return
        END
```

Does anyone know what I need to in Pi to run this thumb style ? 
 EDIT:

for the commands  above I tried adding -mthumb but dont think its right as i dont see any changes.

as -mthumb -o test.o test.s

Comment: The raspberry pi is an arm11 (ARMv6somethingjsomething).  It does not support thumb-2 extensions only thumb.

Comment: I am not sure if it's just thumb or thumb-2 i am needing, the idea is its just 16 registers 1 being the PC. is that just thumb?

Comment: I would try Seva's answer if it is just thumb, that is not how I do it but it seems plausible...github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi I am sure I have some thumb examples there if you want to use .thumb and .thumb_func with the gnu tools.

Answer (score 0):

See if your assembler would take the following line:

```
AREA PrintText, CODE, READONLY, THUMB
```

Comment: Error: bad instruction area PrintText,CODE,READONLY,THUMB

Comment: Oops. Does Pi support Thumb at all?

Comment: Do you know what I need to pass to gcc and as?

Comment: It's a directive in the assembly file, not a command line option. Those vary from one assembler to another; I don't recall them for  GNU `as`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.code 32 @ stuff after this line is arm code

.globl hello_arm
hello_arm:  @an arm function


.thumb @stuff after this line is thumb

.thumb_func @the next function is a thumb function and called properly
.globl hello
hello: @ a thumb function
```